# Pyvis network graph layout

Tags: python, graph, pyvis

Is it possible to create a Pyvis network graph with a layout similar to this image?[Network Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFyxh.png)

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is bend the edges in a 90 degree angles instead of them being connected from A to B.

I've already tried Pyvis and it seems like it uses a static set of algorithms that provide the user with limited customization. I'm also aware that you can add a physics button, but it does not generate the layout that I want to achieve. (The graph that I'm creating is large and has to be interactive. Therefore, the matplotlib library doesn't provide me with a smooth interactive graph).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.